# Haskell: Return the item of a list which absolute difference to its predecessor is equal or smaller than a certain value

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Let's assume I have a list:

`[1, 2, 1.2, 1.8, 1.3, 1.7, 1.35, 1.65...]`

Obviously the absolute difference between one element and its predecessor becomes smaller and smaller. I am looking for a function to return the first value in the list which absolute difference to its predecessor is equal or smaller than a certain value.

The definition should be:

```
approx :: Rational -> [Rational] -> Rational
```

where the first argument is the desired absolute difference and the second is the given list. E.g.:

```
approx 0.4 [1, 2, 1.2, 1.8, 1.3, 1.7, 1.35, 1.65...]
```

This should return `1.7`.

I am pretty new to Haskell. That's why I have a hard time to get into the mindset of functional programming. My idea would be to remove the first item of the list as long as the absolute difference to the next item is not equal or below the desired value, otherwise return the second value. How can I get this idea into Haskell?

Comment: Hint: `zip lst (tail lst)` will give you a list of all adjacent pairs. Because it's lazy, it won't generate pairs that you don't actually need to look at. Use this to construct a list of `(y, abs (x-y))` pairs, where `(x,y)` is an adjacent pair.

Comment: Voting to close. Needs details and clarity.

Comment: I understand that `zip lst (tail lst)` will give me a list like `[(1,2),(2,1.2),(1.2,1.8)...]` but I don't know how to filter so that the condition `abs(x-y)<eps` where `eps` is the threshold is fulfilled.

Comment: Tried  this one: `approx eps list=snd (head (filter (\(x,y)-> abs(x-y) <= eps) zip list (tail list)))`. But something must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, you need to zip the list with its own tail.

Assuming `lst` is `[1, 2, 1.2, 1.8, 1.3, 1.7, 1.35, 1.65]`:

```
zip lst (tail lst)
```

Yields:

```
[(1.0,2.0),(2.0,1.2),(1.2,1.8),(1.8,1.3),(1.3,1.7),(1.7,1.35),(1.35,1.65)]
```

Want the second element from each tuple, *and* the difference between the two values. We'll use `map`.

```
map (\(f, s) -> (s, abs (f - s))) $ zip lst (tail lst)
```

Yields:

```
[(2.0,1.0),(1.2,0.8),(1.8,0.6000000000000001),(1.3,0.5),(1.7,0.3999999999999999),(1.35,0.34999999999999987),(1.65,0.2999999999999998)]
```

Now we just need to find the first element that meets a condition. Let's define a function that can do this. We'll use the `Maybe` type because we might not find anything which satisfies the predicate.

```
findFirst :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> Maybe t
findFirst pred [] = Nothing
findFirst pred (x:xs) = if pred x then Just x else findFirst pred xs
```

And now:

```
findFirst (\(val, diff) -> diff <= 0.4) $ map (\(f, s) -> (s, abs (f - s))) $ zip lst (tail lst)
```

Yields the following, and the data you need just needs to be extracted and all of this logic wrapped up in a function.

```
Just (1.7,0.3999999999999999)
```

As an additional step, we could embellish `findFirst` to make `findFirstAndTransform`.

```
findFirstAndTransform :: (t -> Bool) -> (t -> a) -> [t] -> Maybe a
findFirstAndTransform f t [] = Nothing
findFirstAndTransform f t (x:xs) = if f x then Just (t x) else findFirstAndTransform f t xs
```

And now when we evaluate:

```
findFirstAndTransform (\(val, diff) -> diff <= 0.4) fst $ map (\(f, s) -> (s, abs (f - s))) $ zip lst (tail lst)
```

We get:

```
Just 1.7
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is:

```
approx eps list=snd (head (filter (\(x,y)-> abs(x-y) <= eps) (zip list (tail list))))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).